# Python 3, module 'itertools' has no attribute 'ifilter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I am new at Python, trying to build an old python file into Python 3. I got several build errors which I solved. But at this point I am getting above error. I have no idea how to fix this. The code section looks like below.

```
return itertools.ifilter(lambda i: i.state == "IS", self.storage)
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`itertools.ifilter()` was removed in Python 3 because the built-in [`filter()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) provides the same functionality now.

If you need to write code that can run in both Python 2 and Python 3, use imports from the [`future_builtins` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/future_builtins.html) (only in Python 2, so use a `try...except ImportError:` guard):

```
try:
    # Python 2
    from future_builtins import filter
except ImportError:
    # Python 3
    pass

return filter(lambda i: i.state == "IS", self.storage)
```