# Permute a vector such that an element can't be in the same place

Tags: r, algorithm

I want to permute a vector so that an element can't be in the same place after permutation, as it was in the original.  Let's say I have a list of elements like this: AABBCCADEF

A valid shuffle would be: BBAADEFCCA

But these would be invalid: B**A**ACFEDCAB or BCA**B**FEDCAB

The closest answer I could find was this: [python shuffle such that position will never repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512058/python-shuffle-such-that-position-will-never-repeat). But that's not quite what I want, because there are no repeated elements in that example.

I want a fast algorithm that generalizes that answer in the case of repetitions.

MWE:

```
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(1)
x <- sample(letters, size=295, replace=T)

terrible_implementation <- function(x) {
  xnew <- sample(x)
  while(any(x == xnew)) {
    xnew <- sample(x)
  }
  return(xnew)
}

microbenchmark(terrible_implementation(x), times=10)


Unit: milliseconds
                       expr      min       lq    mean  median       uq      max neval
 terrible_implementation(x) 479.5338 2346.002 4738.49 2993.29 4858.254 17005.05    10
```

Also, how do I determine if a sequence can be permuted in such a way?

EDIT: To make it perfectly clear what I want, the new vector should satisfy the following conditions:

1) `all(table(newx) == table(x))`
2) `all(x != newx)`

E.g.:

```
newx <- terrible_implementation(x)
all(table(newx) == table(x))
[1] TRUE
all(x != newx)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: A vague guess at deciding if the sequence is shuffle-able like this is that the most common element has to have at most `N / 2` repeats - the sequence definitely becomes unshuffleable beyond that, not sure if there are other ways for unshuffleability to occur.

Comment: What's wrong with your implementation?

Comment: I thought I could be clever and only subscramble the elements that did not satisfy the condition. Of course, this won't work if there are more pigeons than pigeonholes.

Comment: @Hugh it's way too slow.  My real data is more like a vector of 1 million, and 1000 unique elements.

Comment: Does the outcome need to have any degree of randomness? Would a Caesar cipher be adequate?

Comment: Would appreciate if randomness could be implemented, but I guess it's not essential.  I'm not sure how a Caesar cipher would be applicable here?

Comment: So replace every A with B, every B with C, ... every Z with A. Or in general every unique element with the 'next' unique element for some ordering. It would be quick (microseconds on your example) but obviously deterministic.

Comment: That would change the number of each letter.  E.g., if my original was ABCC, BCAA wouldn't be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this satisfies all your conditions. The idea is to order by the frequency, start with the most common element and shift the value to the next value in the frequency table by the number of times the most common element appears. This will guarantee all elements will be missed.

I've written in `data.table`, as it helped me during debugging, without losing too much performance. It's a modest improvement performance-wise.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(microbenchmark)


permute_avoid_same_position <- function(y) {
  DT <- data.table(orig = y)
  DT[, orig_order := .I]

  count_by_letter <- 
    DT[, .N, keyby = orig] %>%
    .[order(N)] %>%
    .[, stable_order := .I] %>%
    .[order(-stable_order)] %>%
    .[]

  out <- copy(DT)[count_by_letter, .(orig, orig_order, N), on = "orig"]
  # Dummy element
  out[, new := first(y)]
  origs <- out[["orig"]]
  nrow_out <- nrow(out)
  maxN <- count_by_letter[["N"]][1]

  out[seq_len(nrow_out) > maxN, new := head(origs, nrow_out - maxN)]
  out[seq_len(nrow_out) <= maxN, new := tail(origs, maxN)]

  DT[out, j = .(orig_order, orig, new), on = "orig_order"] %>%
    .[order(orig_order)] %>%
    .[["new"]]
}

set.seed(1)
x <- sample(letters, size=295, replace=T)
testthat::expect_true(all(table(permute_avoid_same_position(x)) == table(x)))
testthat::expect_true(all(x != permute_avoid_same_position(x)))
microbenchmark(permute_avoid_same_position(x), times = 5)

# Unit: milliseconds
#                           expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max
# permute_avoid_same_position(x) 5.650378 5.771753 5.875116 5.788618 5.938604 6.226228

x <- sample(1:1000, replace = TRUE, size = 1e6)
testthat::expect_true(all(table(permute_avoid_same_position(x)) == table(x)))
testthat::expect_true(all(x != permute_avoid_same_position(x)))

microbenchmark(permute_avoid_same_position(x), times = 5)
# Unit: milliseconds
#                           expr      min       lq    mean   median       uq      max
# permute_avoid_same_position(x) 239.7744 385.4686 401.521 438.2999 440.9746 503.0875
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well.  The solution actually seems kind of obvious after you describe the algorithm, lol.

Comment: Great: FYI - I removed the performance bottleneck since you accepted.

Answer (score 4):

```
#DATA
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(letters, size=295, replace=T)

foo = function(S){
    if(max(table(S)) > length(S)/2){
        stop("NOT POSSIBLE")
    }
    U = unique(S)
    done_chrs = character(0)
    inds = integer(0)
    ans = character(0)
    while(!identical(sort(done_chrs), sort(U))){
        my_chrs = U[!U %in% done_chrs]
        next_chr = my_chrs[which.min(sapply(my_chrs, function(x) length(setdiff(which(!S %in% x), inds))))]
        x_inds = which(S %in% next_chr)
        candidates = setdiff(seq_along(S), union(x_inds, inds))
        if (length(candidates) == 1){
            new_inds = candidates
        }else{
            new_inds = sample(candidates, length(x_inds))
        }
        inds = c(inds, new_inds)
        ans[new_inds] = next_chr
        done_chrs = c(done_chrs, next_chr)
    }
    return(ans)
}

ans_foo = foo(x)

identical(sort(ans_foo), sort(x)) & !any(ans_foo == x)
#[1] TRUE

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(foo(x))
#Unit: milliseconds
#   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# foo(x) 19.49833 22.32517 25.65675 24.85059 27.96838 48.61194   100
```

Comment: Does this guarantee a solution if one exists?

Answer (score -2):

We could extract substrings by the boundary of the repeating elements, `sample` and `replicate`

```
library(stringr)
sapply(replicate(10, sample(str_extract_all(str1, "([[:alpha:]])\\1*")[[1]]),
                simplify = FALSE), paste, collapse="")
#[1] "BBAAEFDCCA" "AAAFBBEDCC" "BBAAAEFCCD" "DFACCBBAAE" "AAFCCBBEAD" 
#[6] "DAAAECCBBF" "AAFCCDBBEA" "CCEFADBBAA" "BBAAEADCCF" "AACCBBDFAE"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "AABBCCADEF"
```

Comment: Please have a look at the MWE.  Your solution didn't work on that.

Comment: @thc It is based on your description `A valid shuffle would be: BBAADEFCCA

But these would be invalid: BAACFEDCAB or BCABFEDCAB`

Comment: I understand, but it doesn't work even if I increased replicate from 10 to 1000 on the MWE (not the BBAADEFCCA string).

Comment: @thc If you are looking for unique, then use `!duplicated` or `unique`

Comment: I think I didn't explain my question well... I want the length and content of the new vector to be the same.  So e.g. `table(newx) == table(x)` I will get the same results.  But also `all(x != newx)`.  I'll try to update the description.

Comment: @thc If you look at your example and my example., my example is a string, while yours is a vector (though your description looks like a string).  If you want to get the table, then you have to split the string in my example

Comment: Please look at the code in the post for an example.

Comment: @thc If `res` is my output, then `m1 <- sapply(strsplit(res, ""), table);all(rep(table(strsplit(str1, "")[[1]]), ncol(m1)) == m1)#
[1] TRUE`.  You have a vector and I started with a string.

Comment: As I mentioned, this doesn't work on the example I posted: `str1 <- sample(letters, size=295, replace=T) %>% paste0(collapse="")`.  The second condition: `any(sapply(strsplit(res,""), function(r) all(r == strsplit(str1,""))))# [1] FALSE`

Comment: @thc My conditional statement is different

Comment: Yes, it is different than the conditions required by the question.  That's why it doesn't work on the example I posted.