# Fast randomly-paired permutation

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, random, permutation

I need to generate a randomly-paired permutation for an ordered array of integers (indexes). For example, for `N=10` the input array looks like:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

A valid randomly-paired permutation would be:

```
[7 8 6 5 9 3 2 0 1 4]
```

Notice that the indexes are randomly-paired, i.e.: if element `0` (input array) is paired with `7` (`0`th position in the permuted array), then element `7` (input array) is paired with `0` (`7`th position in the permuted array), etc.
No element in the input array can be paired with itself, i.e. this is not a valid permutation:

```
[7 1 6 5 9 3 2 0 8 4]
```

because the elements `1` and `8` are in their "index" positions. This is related to [derangement permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), a topic already covered a few times in SO:

- [Generate a random derangement of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25200220/1391441)
- [Shuffle list, ensuring that no item remains in same position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7279895/1391441)
- [python shuffle such that position will never repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15512058/1391441)

I'm not certain how (if) I could use any of the answers listed there to my benefit.
The code below does what I need, but it becomes very slow for large `N` values. I need to perform this operation thousands of times for `N ~ 1500`, meaning this method is of no use.

I'm positive there must be a more clever way to do this.

```
N = 10
idxs = np.arange(N)

# Generate a shuffled array
input_idxs = idxs.copy()
np.random.shuffle(input_idxs)

# Empty array to store the final randomly paired indexes
shuffled_idxs = np.zeros(N, dtype=int)

used_idxs = []
for i in idxs:
    if i not in used_idxs:
        for j in input_idxs:
            if j not in used_idxs:
                if j != i:
                    shuffled_idxs[i] = j
                    shuffled_idxs[j] = i
                    used_idxs.append(i)
                    used_idxs.append(j)
                    break
```

Comment: Just to make sure if I understand this correctly: Your goal is to randomly swap elements in your list with the requirements that every number is only swapped once, correct?

Comment: I guess you could think of it that way. The main point is that the random swaps must be done in pairs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pairing of swaps would imply that N is always an even number.  If that is the case, then you can take a sample of half the indexes and pair them with a shuffled list of the remaining indexes:

```
import random
def randomPairs(N):
    result = [None] * N
    A  = random.sample(range(N),N//2)
    B  = random.sample(list(set(range(N))-set(A)),N//2)
    for a,b in zip(A,B):
        result[a] = b
        result[b] = a
    return result

for _ in range(10):
    print(randomPairs(6))

[4, 3, 5, 1, 0, 2]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[5, 3, 4, 1, 2, 0]
[2, 3, 0, 1, 5, 4]
[3, 2, 1, 0, 5, 4]
[2, 3, 0, 1, 5, 4]
[4, 2, 1, 5, 0, 3]
[3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2]
[2, 3, 0, 1, 5, 4]
[1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4]
```

**Performance**

```
# 1000 shuffles of 1500 elements in pairs
def test1():
    for _ in range(1000):
        randomPairs(1500)
        
from timeit import timeit
count = 1

t = timeit(test1,number=count)
print(t) # 1.12 seconds
```

[EDIT] a slightly faster solution would be to shuffle all the indexes and pair every other position with the next one in the shuffled list:

```
import random
def randomPairs(N):
    result = [None] * N
    A  = random.sample(range(N),N)
    for a,b in zip(A[::2],A[1::2]):
        result[a] = b
        result[b] = a
    return result
```