# Pairing rows of a file almost randomly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file say `file1.rule`, which has even number of rows, the last column of that file represent `fitness` and the second last column represent the `class`. I want to pair the rows class wise(first picks the row with the highest fitness then a random one from the remaining), with just one condition that no two identical rows can form a pair. In my file, no two exactly identical row for a class can occur more than `n/2` times where `n` is the number of rows for that particular class.

Below is my file:

```
*,*,*,1,0,1.0
*,*,1,*,0,0.22
*,*,2,2,1,0.71
*,*,2,2,1,0.71
*,2,2,*,1,0.64
*,2,2,*,1,0.64
1,*,*,3,2,0.95
*,*,3,2,2,0.66
*,*,3,4,2,0.67
3,*,*,*,2,0.33
3,*,*,*,2,0.33
3,*,*,*,2,0.33
```

And the code for this :

```
rule_file_name = "file1.rule"
from collections import defaultdict
list1 = []

with open(rule_file_name) as rule_fp:
    for line in rule_fp.readlines():
        list1.append(line.replace("\n","").split(","))

assert len(list1) & 1 == 0
classes = defaultdict(list)
for _list in list1:
    classes[_list[4]].append(_list)

    
from random import sample, seed
seed(1)
for key, _list in classes.items():
    assert len(_list) & 1 == 0
    _list.sort(key=lambda x: x[5])
    pairs = []
    #while(len(_list)>2):
    while _list:
        #print(len(_list))
        first = _list[-1]
        candidate = sample(_list, 1)[0]
        if first != candidate:
            #print(f'first{first}, candidate{candidate}')
            print(f'{first},{candidate}')
            pairs.append((first, candidate))
            _list.remove(first)
            _list.remove(candidate)
    classes[key] = pairs
```

The above code is working fine for class 0 and 1 and pairing is done but for class 2, the first 2 randomly chosen pairs are :

```
['1', '*', '*', '3', '2', '0.95'],['*', '*', '3', '2', '2', '0.66']
['*', '*', '3', '4', '2', '0.67'],['3', '*', '*', '*', '2', '0.33']
```

Now after these the remaining 2 rows of class 2 are: `3,*,*,*,2,0.33 and 3,*,*,*,2,0.33` which are identical so they can't form a pair and hence the while loop is running for infinite times.

According to my observation, this condition will only arrive when there are only last 2 rows left for any class, in this case, I simply want to discard those 2 rows. So I tried to replace the while condition writing: `while(len(_list)>2):` , but in this case the last 2 will always be ignored even if they are completely different from each other. What to do?

Can I use any timer inside the while loop like below?

```
if some_condition or time.time() > timeout:
        break
```

I tried to modify the code like this also:

```
while _list:
    first = _list[-1]
    _list.remove(first)
    candidate = sample(_list, 1)[0]
    if (len(_list)<=2) and first == candidate:
        break
    elif first != candidate:
        #print(f'first{first}, candidate{candidate}')
        print(f'{first},{candidate}')
        pairs.append((first, candidate))
        #_list.remove(first)
        _list.remove(candidate)
classes[key] = pairs
```

But in this,when my file looks like below:

```
*,2,2,*,1,0.64
*,*,2,2,1,0.71
*,*,2,2,1,0.71
*,2,2,*,1,0.64
```

It is selecting `['*', '*', '2', '2', '1', '0.71'],['*', '2', '2', '*', '1', '0.64']` then I am getting error in `candidate = sample(_list, 1)[0]` this line saying: `ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative`. Please help me out.

Comment: "bitwise and" with 1 return 0 for even values. This is correct for your logic?

Comment: @Eugene Yes that thing is correct because I will always have even number of rows in total and each class will also have even number of rows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fast randomly-paired permutation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65361557/fast-randomly-paired-permutation)

Comment: Error for second version becouse you want get value from empty list. In past iteration your list have one element, but checking length of list stay letter sample  calling

Comment: @Sneftel No, actually my question is different from that.

Comment: @Eugene why empty list? Can you elaborate a little please?

Comment: Your code remove last element in list in ```_list.remove(first)``` and call sample for empty list. Becouse in list odd values and on each iteration remove pair of elements.

Comment: Can you please give me one solution? I am new to programming and python hence facing difficulty.

Comment: Check condition with length before remove element from list.

Comment: `if (len(_list)<=2) and first == candidate:
 break
_list.remove(first)
elif first != candidate:`  are you saying something like this? But I think this will throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be one direction to go in:

```py
# ...
# construct the defaultdict classes as before.

from collections import Counter
from random import seed, choice


def attempt_partition_into_pairs(rows):
    rows.sort(key=lambda x: x[5])
    # convert to tuples so that the rows are hashable.
    rows = [tuple(row) for row in rows]
    # convert to a Counter so that we organize duplicates
    counter = Counter(rows)

    pairs = []

    # ensure there are always at least two distinct rows
    while len(counter) >= 2:
        # choose and remove first
        first = rows.pop()
        counter[first] -= 1
        if counter[first] == 0:
            del counter[first]

        # choose candidate
        while True:
            candidate = choice(rows)
            if candidate != first:
                break
        counter[candidate] -= 1
        if counter[candidate] == 0:
            del counter[candidate]
        rows.remove(candidate)

        # output
        assert candidate != first
        print(f'{first},{candidate}')
        pairs.append((first, candidate))

    return pairs


seed(1)
for key, _list in classes.items():
    assert len(_list) & 1 == 0
    classes[key] = attempt_partition_into_pairs(_list)
```

This prints:

```
('*', '*', '*', '1', '0', '1.0'),('*', '*', '1', '*', '0', '0.22')
('*', '*', '2', '2', '1', '0.71'),('*', '2', '2', '*', '1', '0.64')
('*', '*', '2', '2', '1', '0.71'),('*', '2', '2', '*', '1', '0.64')
('1', '*', '*', '3', '2', '0.95'),('3', '*', '*', '*', '2', '0.33')
('*', '*', '3', '4', '2', '0.67'),('3', '*', '*', '*', '2', '0.33')
('*', '*', '3', '2', '2', '0.66'),('3', '*', '*', '*', '2', '0.33')
```

I've taken the liberty to factor out that function. Using a `collections.Counter` helps keeps track of when there are duplicates. Also you can you `random.choice()` rather than `random.sample(..., 1)`.

This technically retains some `O(n^2)` behavior at the `rows.remove(candidate)` call, so it may be a bit slow if your input file is huge, but certainly no slower than your original attempt. You can probably fix that with some more cleverness, if need be.

Comment: This looks fine and got the concept as well. Thanks.